# Нужна ли запятая в моём предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Иногда замечания горожан находят отклик у автолюбителей, и те сбавляют громкость...» нужна запятая? Склоняюсь, что да...

Answer (score 1):

***Иногда** замечания горожан находят отклик у автолюбителей, *и (тогда)* те сбавляют громкость...*

Запятая ставится – наречие «иногда» следует отнести к первому предложению. Дело в том, что отношения между предложениями не однородные, а **взаимообусловленные**: если замечания находят отклик, то тогда автолюбители снижают скорость.

**Общий элемент** может связывать только однородные (независимые по смыслу) предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, относит автор слово "иногда" только к первой части предложения или к обеим его частям. В первом случае запятая нужна, во втором "иногда" станет общим элементом и запятая будет не нужна.